# Наследование классов в CSS

Tags: css

Привет.
Мне не в лом проверить эту теорию но интересно ваше мнение.

```
.font
{
@import fontcolor.css,
@import fontweight.css,
.f8px,
.f10px,
.f11px
}
```

Можно ли так использовать классы, вложенные в другие классы, при проектировании своего CSS фреймворка?
Можно ли подгружать таким образом наборы классов через импорты или лучше писать наборы через тоже наследование?
Можно ли создать фреймворк по схеме MVC?(да в некотором роде это будет псевдореализация)

Comment: Ну так проверьте! Зачем мнение-то спрашивать?

Comment: Мне было бы влом писать вопрос, я бы уже проверил.

Comment: аналогично...

Comment: Это же не совсем css. Что это?

Answer (score 2):

По поводу `@import` в класс - [тут](http://htmlbook.ru/css/import) утверждают:

> > > Правило @import позволяет импортировать содержимое CSS-файла в текущую стилевую таблицу. @import не разрешается вставлять после любых объявлений кроме @charset или другого @import.